# Como agregar una toolbar en un fragment

Tags: java, android

alguien sabe como implementar una toolbar en un fragment?
Estuve intentando con:

```
((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolAlb);
```

Pero no logro que funcione, me manda un nullpointer

Alguna sugerencia?

aqui mi fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_album_frgament, container, false);
        toolAlb=vista.findViewById(R.id.toolbarAB);
        AppCompatActivity activity= (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
if(toolAlb!=null) {
            Log.d("onCreateView: ", "tool  " + toolAlb.getTransitionName());
            activity.setSupportActionBar(toolAlb);
        }
}
```

Estoy utilizando:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

Una disculpa ya encontre que el error no esta al inflar el toolbar,
esta al tratar de cambiar su visibilidad, al inflarla esta invisible y trato de cambiarla desde un menu contextual, es ahi donde me manda:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Esto mismo lo hago en una activity y funciona correctamente, solo en el fragment es donde me da problemas

Este es mi menu contextual:

```
  @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            AdaptadorBiblioteca.listas();
            int selected=item.getOrder();
            Listas.listas();
            String ruta;
            File fvr;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case 120:
                listChk=new ArrayList<>();
                recyclerView.removeAllViews();
                for(int q=0;q<ListItems.size();q++){
                    if(q!=selected){
                        listChk.add(false);
                    }else {
                        tmp=ListItems.get(q);
                        listChk.add(true);
                    }
                }
                adpSelect=new AdpSelect(ListItems,listChk);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adpSelect);
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(selected);
                toolAlb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
    }
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola David, para poder ayudarte necesitamos ver la porción de código relacionada con el problema, tienes **toolAlb = "null"**, solo estoy adivinando.

Comment: Esta es la parte en la que me lanza el error de nullpointer al inflar el toolbar. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema es el contexto, para obtener el contexto desde un Fragment que en realidad serìa la Activity que lo contiene debes usar [getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#getActivity()) :

```
//((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolAlb);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolAlb);
```